# How to create a NAS based storage pool?

Tags: nas, storage, storage-pool

How can I create a NAS-based storage pool that takes my disks on the network, create partitions and an FS and give me a combined pool totaling the sum of all the storage devices?

I know a similar thing can be achieved with ZFS for all drives attached to a single system and all use the same OS. I need the same for NAS with same/different OS, partitions, FSs, etc.

I'm ready to align my stack to one OS, FS, partition, given such a thing works.

For e.g., I have 8 1TiB drives, the pool should give me a pool that is 8TiB in size and works using NAS.

Comment: What’s your goal? Several PCs on a network, each with some HDDs, using a single distributed file system access all HDDs? Or perhaps multiple (separate) storage locations accessible through one “portal” (virtual file system)?

Comment: Which OS are you using? TrueNAS has pretty extensive documentation.

Comment: I wanna leverage many disks on many systems to be a single pool if possible different OSes even if they're the same flavor (as I only use Linux) However, I'm willing to make them all the same if it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you actually want a so-called [distributed file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#Distributed_file_systems) (not to be confused with Microsoft DFS). A distributed file system has the following characteristics:

- All hosts share the same view of the entire storage with all files and directories that exist across all hosts
- All hosts can access everything as if it were on a local drive
- The hosts *do not* access others’ block storage directly

Because of the required consensus protocols etc. you won’t get “local performance”.

There are many implementations to choose from. The widest known ones are CephFS and GlusterFS, I guess.

I suggest you try with a small-scale deployment (for example in VMs) first.

Keep in mind however that these file systems are not designed for use with nodes that are only online sometimes. All nodes are expected to be online all the time except for maintenance or defects.

Comment: Thanks, I actually know Ceph and used it for K8s integration, but never thought of this use with CephFS.

Comment: I actually don't want same files and directories synced across all hosts.
Put it simply, I need something where all hosts can see the files and directories on disks that are on different systems, not necessarily have all that data locally. They're just able to see and retrieve as they want by copying(using SMB etc.), I don't know if such a thing exists.

Comment: They are not synced.

Comment: Oh, thanks man, that's great.